# Vue Apexchart timeline: dataLabel still visible even items aren't visible in the chart (time has passed or not met)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, apexcharts

[vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs)
[apexcharts](/questions/tagged/apexcharts)

Hi, I have an issue and not sure if it was a bug or I have missed for some configuration. Currently I'm flowing the [Timeline Charts](https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/timeline-charts/distributed/) here.  I have to enable for the label, and you can see when the time of a task have passed, or not met (by dragging the chart), but the label of hide item is still visible and be stacked with visible label

[Issue example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uegTU.png)

[Issue example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MVqT.png)

Any body got the same issues yet and how to resolve it? I don't think it's a bug because obiviously no one expected this behavior, right?

I have tried for most of the configuration in the dataLabels but nothing kind related to this. Feel free to drag the chart to see the issue clearly. The code is basically a demo from Apexchart demo, not modify much. You could easily download the original code here: https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/

Demo for the issue: `jsfiddle.net/xhieu2206/quvzaxk9`

<strike>P/s: after checking for a jsfiddle of the same usecase in React, it work normally without any configuration, so seem like it's a bug from Vue Apexchart team, please correct me if I was wrong (hopefully ...) ...</strike>

Demo in react: `jsfiddle.net/xhieu2206/3fzb60ar/2/`

Editted: the issue happened with react too:

demo: `jsfiddle.net/xhieu2206/3fzb60ar/2`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZghuW.png)

Comment: Consider inclusion of the applicable code / script that has a problem pertaining to your question.

Comment: sorry I couldn't do that because of my repository privacy, and it's quite complicated and having alot of un-related thing in it. But we could simple use the source code from the demo of Vue Apexcharts, it could bery easy to reproduce the issue in it (I have done that in the jsfiddle)